# Default timeout for Apache commons TelnetClient, java

Tags: java, telnet

I'm using the apache telnetclient library to connect to a switch with a  telnet connection, but the problem i'm having is the setDefaultTimeout method will not work. instead of timing out in 1 second like i want,

`telnetClient.setDefaultTimeout(1000);`

it takes up 20 seconds to timeout. Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this page http://www.ioncannon.net/java/132/connection-timeouts-with-the-apache-commons-telnetclient/. turns out it was changed to `setConnectTimeout(int)` instead of `setDefaultTimeout(1000)`

Answer (score 1):

telnetClient.setConnectTimeout(timeout);this is connect timeout time
telnetClient.setSoTimeout(timeout);  this is block time